# Undefined method 'any?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

I'm trying to create a validator that validates whether a user typed in a clean word. I'm using the Obscenity gem but created some of my own methods to ensure quality data.

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  @mystery_words = # This is a mystery, I can't tell you.
  @mystery_c = @mystery_words.map(&:capitalize)
  @mystery_u = @mystery_words.map(&:upcase)
  @mysteries = @mystery_words + @mystery_c + @mystery_u
  @new_mysteries = @mysteries.map{|mystery|mystery.tr("A-Za-z", "N-ZA-Mn-za-m")}

  def validate (user)
    if Obscenity.profane?(user.name) \ 
    || @new_mysteries.any?{|mystery|user.name.include?(mystery)} \
    || @new_mysteries.any?{|mystery|user.email.include?(mystery)} \
    || @new_mysteries.any?{|mystery|user.password.include?(mystery)}
      user.errors[:name] << 'Error: Please select a different username'
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
```

**Error Message**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method any? for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand why I received that message.

Comment: Looks like you've defined `@new_mysteries` on the class, rather than on the instance

Comment: Can you please format so that horizontal scrolling is not required?  Here, two ways (that do not need the line-continuation character `\ `) would be to break after `||` or `{ |..|`.

Comment: That's fine, and much better, but just so that you know, you could put `||` at the end of each line, without the line-continuation character.

Comment: @Cary- Thank you for the advice. I thought for sure you needed the escape character when you wanted a new line.

Comment: I had a quick look for docs for Ruby's implied line continuation rules, but came up empty. (A link, anyone?).  If Ruby can reason that the line is to continue (e.g., if it ends with a comma or an operator), it's OK. For `a.map...`, you can write `a.` on line 1 and `map...` on line 2.  For Ruby v1.9+ you can write `a` on line 1 and `.map...` on line 2.  For chained operations like `a.uniq.first(n).map...`, you may see `a.uniq` on line 1, `.first(n)` on line 2 and `.map...` on the line 3, often with the dots aligned vertically. Note that valid line continuations sometimes confuse IRB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `@new_mysteries` on the class, rather than on the instance.

Consider:

```
class MyValidator

  @new_mysteries = ['a','b','c']

  def validate
    p @new_mysteries
  end
end

MyValidator.new.validate
# => nil
```

Inside the `validate` method, `@` variables refer to variables on the instance (an instance created by `new`). Outside of a method definition, `@` variables refer to instances of the class itself. Hence the disconnect.

I would probably declare `@new_mysteries` inside the constructor:

```
class MyValidator

  def initialize
    @new_mysteries = ['a','b','c']
  end

  def validate
    p @new_mysteries
  end
end

MyValidator.new.validate
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Further reading: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue of variable scope in your code. Try following:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def mystery_setup
    @mystery_words = # This is a mystery, I can't tell you.
    @mystery_c = @mystery_words.map(&:capitalize)
    @mystery_u = @mystery_words.map(&:upcase)
    @mysteries = @mystery_words + @mystery_c + @mystery_u
    @new_mysteries = @mysteries.map { |mystery| mystery.tr("A-Za-z", "N-ZA-Mn-za-m") }
  end

  def validate(user)
    mystery_setup

    if Obscenity.profane?(user.name) || @new_mysteries.any?{|mystery|user.name.include?(mystery)} || @new_mysteries.any?{|mystery|user.email.include?(mystery)} \
    || @new_mysteries.any?{|mystery|user.password.include?(mystery)}
      user.errors[:name] << 'Error: Please select a different username'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue with the method any, but I get the same NilClass Error for include? as well. Is that also an issue with scope?

Comment: If `user.name.include?` is throwing exception, it says `name` attr os your `user` object is nil.

Comment: In that case, I should probably call the validation on :create so a user can be created